# weird positioning problem while rotating image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rotation

I am running into a weird positioning issue while rotating an image wrapped into a div in JavaScript. When rotating the image by either 90 or 270 degrees, the image suddenly is 50px above and 50px to the right of its parent div. For 0 or 180 degrees it's just fine.

This is what I am doing:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="crop_container" style="width:400px; height:400px; border:solid 1px;">
        <img src="http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/249740_10150195623627623_506197622_7383520_7286937_n.jpg" style="display:block; position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;" />
    </div>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    var $cropContainer =  $("#crop_container");
    var $cropImage =  $("#crop_container img");
    var degrees = 90;

    $cropImage.css({"width":400, "height":300});
    $cropContainer.css({"width":300, "height":400});
    $cropImage.css({"-webkit-transform":"rotate("+degrees+"deg)","-moz-transform":"rotate("+degrees+"deg)"});
    //$cropImage.css({"top":50, "right":50});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when you uncommect the last css adjustment line with a correction of 50px from top and right it works just fine, but I have no clue as to why this is happening?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Joni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you expect it to do. It is rotating around the midpoint of the image, not the rectangle.

- Midpoint placeholder: `(150, 200)`
- Midpoint image: `(200, 150)`.

Indeed, there is a `50px` difference. You could change the midpoint of rotating *before* rotating by translating:

```
translate(-50px, 50px) rotate("+degrees+"deg)
```

so that the image midpoint becomes `(200 - 50, 150 + 50)` which is `(150, 200)`, what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/4UUJN/2/

Comment: Project is almost done now & working on x-browser issues. I ran into trouble with IE8. I'm using the HeyGrady 2D transfrom JQuery plugin for rotating and provide it the translation as you suggested, which works fine on FF/Chrome/Safari/IE9. The plugin project page mentions that "IE also lacks support for transform-origin and translate() [...] The jQuery Transform plug-in handles these calculations automatically" (see: https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki/correcting-transform-origin-and-translate-in-ie).  However, it does not seem to do so. Anyone has any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: @Joni: I'd say you ought to post a separate question for that - nobody will really notice a comment somewhere in a question that already has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate a landscape image by 90 degrees into a portrait image it will keep it centered to it's original position. Since your width and height are 100 pixels apart from one another, the transform distributes the difference to the top and bottom, that's where your 50 pixels comes from.